# Magento2: Add new Field in Cart page and Save in order?

Tags: magento2

I want to Add new Field "Remark"  in Cart Items Page.
it is a purpose to  "Remark" for product.
When i save cart(Update cart) it will be saved in Quote items table. also "Procced To checkout" It will be saved in order detials.
Also view in admin side

Comment: its unclear what you are asking , add sufficient details address the problem and feature

Comment: 0
down vote
favorite
I want to Add new Field "Remark" in Cart Items Page. it is a purpose to "Remark" for product. When i save cart(Update cart) it will be saved in Quote items table. also "Procced To checkout" It will be saved in order detials. Also view in admin side

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I also need to save an extra input field to a custom field I have added in to quote_item table. but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 2):

Magento provides additional attribute functionality to pass additional data. On cart page, create input field for remark then in custom module's events.xml, create an observer like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customremark" instance="Companyname\Modulename\Observer\customremark" />
    </event>

</config>
```

Then in observer, you can get this remark field from request

```
<?php

namespace Companyname\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check and set information according to your need
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') { //checking when product is adding to cart
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $additionalOptions = [];
            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => "Remark",
                'value' => "Your Information",
            );
            $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not Dynemmically Corrent. I dont want to add "Custom Option".                   i just want to add field in Quote table..set Quote table . and add field in Order items table and Save in order system. that;s it

Comment: @Envision Ecommerce - Is this support cart proceed to checkout button. I think its a KO js request.I have added cutom fields to checkout page , its a long process. :(

Comment: thanks, adding to custom options is much less hassle than adding a field to quote item